# Labelling multiple points from CSV in basemap

Tags: python, gis, matplotlib-basemap

I'm having issues labeling all the points plotted with the code below,
each row in the CSV file is `name`, `lat`,`lon`.
Points are plotting just fine.

Everything I've tried to have names be plotted along x,y has borked everything in one way or another.
Anyone have any tips?

```
with open('/.../geo/ALL.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',')
    for data in reader:
        names.append(str(data[0]))
        lats.append(float(data[1]))
        lons.append(float(data[2]))
x,y = map(lons,lats)
map.plot(x,y,'r*',markersize=0.02,color='yellow',marker='D')
```

Comment: My tip is to try pandas. Also, I definitely need more info, like the specific error you're encountering to make any useful suggestions beyond that.

Comment: Sadly, there is no real error.
some methods results in no points being plotted, some in the map having an EKG style diagram vs the plotted points.

Comment: what is the point of this line: `x,y = map(lons,lats)` ?

Comment: My understanding is translates the lat and lon from the CSV row to the x,y.

Comment: @Geekymutt is your goal to plot a dot in the xy plane corresponding to each `lon` and its corresponding `lat`?

Comment: yes, that's part of the project. the other part is labeling each. The program pulls,saves and plots every point, on a cron job every few minutes. and that much as worked really well for a few days, now I need to label each point with the corresponding name, eventually I'll need to add a icon that can be pointed in the direction of motion.

Answer (score 1):

You goal is to plot (`lons`,`lats`) points in the xy-plane with a label on each. This is one way to do it:

```
import csv, matplotlib.pyplot as plt

names, lats, lons = [], [], []

with open('file.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',')
    for data in reader:
        names.append(str(data[0]))
        lats.append(float(data[1]))
        lons.append(float(data[2]))


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(lats, lons, marker='*', s=400) # play with 's' to control the dot size
pad = "   " # play with this to pad the label from the dot
for i, n in enumerate(names):
    ax.annotate(pad+str(n), (lats[i], lons[i])) 

plt.savefig("scatter.png") # you will find scatter.png file in the same directory
```

This is the `scatter.png` I get:

[image]

with this `file.csv` CSV file:

```
n1,1,8
n4,7,2
n2,3,14
n7,13,4
n5,9,6
n6,11,12
n3,5,10
n8,15,18
n9,17,16
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't seem to work for me. It wouldn't even generate the map with that.

Comment: @Geekymutt can you show how your `map` is created (basically show more code). Did you see [this](https://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plotting_data.html#plot) ?